# Place button inside input form with flex

Tags: html, css, forms, input, flexbox

I was able to get the form I want to have the button placed inside the input form but when as the screen size gets smaller the form and button don't stack on top of one another like they would if the button wasn't place inside the form.

Basically I want the button inside the form on desktop and stacked on top of one another for mobile. Any ideas?
If I change the button position to relative then it can't be placed in form

[Image of form on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq1GZ.png)

[Image of form on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k19mA.png)

```css
.button {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  border-radius: 50px !important;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: 5px !important;
}

#form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #url-25 {
    flex-direction: column !important;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0 20px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="text">
  <input type="submit" value="BUILD YOUR APP"></input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed some properties in your code based on your requirement. Chcek the snippet below. The button will be inside the input on desktop and it will be stacked in mobile (Under 567px).

And a few changes I did in your code includes:

- There was style for `.button` which wasn't present
- There was style for `#url-25` which was also not there.
- Input submit changed to button submit.
- Removed unnecessary `!important`s.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 567px) {
  #form {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  button, input {
     position: static;
     width: 100%;
     border-radius: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="text">
    <button type="submit">BUILD YOUR APP</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh my apologies! Forgot to remove the irrelevant id. It seems to be working when screen size is smaller but not recognizing the flex-end when on safari browser. Also when stacked where would I add padding so there's a little space between the form and button when stacked?

Comment: Where are you using `flex-end`. ?

Comment: Sorry, justify content: end. The button is showing up on the left side in safari. Looking great on other browsers

Comment: It should be `flex-end`, in the snippet it is `end`. Can you try that and let me know ? I will update the snippet too

Comment: I've tried using various webkit methods but no dice. This should be recognized on Safari. Thoughts?

Comment: But since we are using `position`, the `flex-end` may not be required to poisiton the button to the right end.

Comment: It should, which version of safari are you using? Some older versions may not have 100% support on `flexbox`. But still it should align to right since we are using `position`

Comment: I checked in my safari and seems to be working :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236773/discussion-between-frankieseattle-and-abin-thaha).

Comment: Something is overriding. When screen size decreases they stack layered on each other instead of one on top of another

Answer (score 1):

A couple of comments here.

There is a url-25 in the media query but no url-25 id in the given code, and nothing changes the #form layout on changing the media size.

Also, there several !importants in the media query which appear to have no function, at least given the code in the question.

```css
<style>
.button{
            font-size: 16px !important;
            border-radius: 50px !important;
            position: absolute;
            margin-right: 5px !important;
    }


   

     #form{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: end;
    }

    @media (max-width: 800px) {
        #form{
             flex-direction: column;
             align-items: stretch;
             width: 100%;
             padding: 0 20px;    
  }
        }
        </style>
```

```html
<form id="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="text">
    <input type="submit" value="BUILD YOUR APP"></input>
</form>
```